# Как растянуть видео в vimeo?

Tags: html, css, видео, vimeo

Как сделать объект-fit: cover; как в css. Видео обрезано по бокам. Как это исправить? Я хочу поместить его на фон сайта.

iframe code :
`<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/767578091?background=1&muted=1&autoplay=1&dnt=1" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media;" allowfullscreen></iframe>`
[image]

Я прочитал это руководство, но оно помогло лишь сделать его фоновым и не растянуло. Есть идея растянуть с помощью scale, но думаю что лучше это сделать с готовыми методами если таковые есть. Я руководствовался официальным гайдом: [ссылка](https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011183028-Embedding-background-and-chromeless-videos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так?

```css
.iframe-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.iframe-wrapper iframe {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 56.25vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 177.77vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

h1 {
    color: white;
}
p {
    color: gold;
}
a {
    color: lime;
}
```

```html
 <div class="iframe-wrapper">
 <iframe
 src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/767578091?background=1&muted=1&autoplay=1&dnt=1" webkitallowfullscreen
 mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
 <h1>Demo</h1>
 <p>Плохо ищете.) <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/37309881/8206804">Взято здесь.</a></p>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Измените *width* (ширина) и *height* (высота) до нужных размеров (пикселях)

Comment: Или max-width и max-height

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]